# Shift Tab for showing the documentation of a command in Jupyter Notebook is not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem in using the shortcut 'shift tab' in order to get more informations of the package or command I am typing in in a cell. I installed Jupyter notebook via anaconda very recently, I am using python 3.7 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Do you know how to fix this problem ? I googled a lot but could not find a solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Follow two steps:

Step 1: Run that cell first (`shift + enter)`

Step 2: After running the cell, press the `shift + tab.`

It worked for me. I hope it will work for you too :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you wrote the below code and trying to get the signature/documentation of function read_csv() with Shift+Tab (It may not work some times)

**Code:**
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv()

-> First type only below code

pd.read_csv?   ## Execute this code with Shift+Enter

-> Now when you type pd.read_csv and type Shift+Tab, this will show u signature/documentation... This is just a workaround...

Answer (score 2):

In the menu bar there is a little trust button just verify it is trusted if not then run Shift+Tab inside the parenthesis , it should work

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Colab environment, if fixed it as follows:
Tools | Settings | Editor |uncheck Automatically trigger code inspection.
Then, Tab and Shift-Tab worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Run again your line of importing the libraries. Now, having loaded your modules you should be able to see the command documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Run the import command on the library of which you're trying to see the docs then try the shift + tab and it should work just fi

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem but can you confirm that you imported the library in the jupyter notebook and then were calling one of the methods of the library?

What I observed is that if the library wasn't imported into the notebook then the documentation wasn't also showing using Shift+Tab. Once I imported it, then the shortcut was working to show the documentation.

*Scenario 1:

import numpy as np #Pressed Enter for next line

a=np.random.randint #Shift + Tab not working*

***Scenario 2:

import numpy as np #Shift + Enter

a=np.random.randint #Shift + Tab working***

Answer (score 0):

Just Run the tab of your code
Then bring your curser in the parenthesis and press shift + tab
press shift + tab + tab for more info

Answer (score 0):

On Google colab:

- clicking on the function after running,
- move the cursor away and then
- bring the mouse and hover it over causes it to pop up.
- Note: colab Tools | Settings | Editor | check Automatically trigger code inspection (first setting)

Answer (score 0):

Try FN + TAB first!
Then, click out and click back and try SHIFT + TAB again.